# Why would a customer have a connection issue with our Android app but not others?

Tags: android, permissions, connection

We have some Android apps on Google Play and iPhone apps on the Apple App Store.

We're getting some sporadic reports that our Android app is having connection issues (the first thing you have to do in all the versions is login with a username/password). The calls to our system are going through using SOAP web services.

In at least once instance we're being told that the same person who has an issue with the Android app is logging in just fine from an iPhone. This person (and others) is also reporting that other Android apps on their Android phone that access the Internet just fine.

We're not seeing the failed attempt in our logs, so it seems that the connection attempt is not even making it to us.

But, assuming there's not some user error and these reports are accurate, is there any reason an Android phone block our app from accessing the Internet, but not others? And if there is some sort of permission granting thing happening (we have `android.permission.INTERNET` in the manifest and like I said, it works for most people just fine) why would it not affect more apps on the user's phone?

Comment: If they are on WiFi, maybe some firewall settings on the router?  If 3G, maybe some settings/blocks on the network side?

Comment: @AleksG: I forgot to mention that these are all SOAP web service calls, so it uses the same port as web browsers (443, since it's SSL). But I'd be interested to see if there's such a thing as blocks on the network side since some (but not all) of the problem users are on prepaid networks.